# Facebook sharing data with 3rd party companies

Tags: facebook

From what I heard, Facebook shared users' info with Cambridge Analytica.

Didn't they made it clear in their long terms and conditions (which people tick without reading) that they can do that?

Comment: Hi, You may refer the entire story and the background on the following Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook-Cambridge_Analytica_data_scandal. This covers the entire story including FB's response.

Comment: I read that already before asking the question but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Hope you have read the Responses section - where the Facebook has apologized for their mistake or breach of trust.... A organization accepting it as a mistake means they breached the contract/terms and condition with users. Hope this clarifies...

Comment: @Sayan: Has Facebook ever apologized for sharing information with the Obama campaign?  Or for any of the thousands of developers of apps on their platform who they gave access to user data and didn't happen to end up in the news for being affiliated with Republican politicians?

Comment: They can share it with anyone and they do share it when it serves certain interests. Nothing you can do about it except stop using it.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I'm not sure about Obama's case. What I was referring is on below links:
https://edition.cnn.com/2018/03/25/europe/facebook-zuckerberg-cambridge-analytica-sorry-ads-newspapers-intl/index.html

https://www.recode.net/2018/3/25/17161262/facebook-cambridge-analytica-apology-ads-newspapers-data-washington-post-new-york-times